# Modal Appearing on a web Browser but not on a device in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Modal Appearing on a web Browser but not on a device in ionic 2. See the code below. What might be the problem?

```
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { ModalPage } from './modal-page';

    export class MyPage {
      constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
      }

      presentModal() {
        let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
        modal.present();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you check if there is any error occurring in catch of `modal.present()`. You can do this by using `modal.present().then().catch((x) => {alert("Error :" + x);})` kind of code.

Comment: @SagarKulkarni Thanks

Comment: @SagarKulkarni The problem is that is filling the page. I think it should pop up ? How can I do it. Thanks